# How to join on only distinct ids in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two database tables, like this:

```
**policies**
- policy_id
- transaction_date

**insured_items**
- policy_id
- postcode
- item_type
```

The `policies` table can have many duplicated `policy_id` records with different `transaction_date` values, but I just want to join the distinct `policy_id` records to the `insured_items` table on the `policy_id` column.

How can I do this join without including duplicated records?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hmm I think I missed something, why not just select policy_id and item_type from the table insured_items?

Comment: OP probably wants to grab a transaction_date (max?) as well.

Comment: Any foreign keys? (E.g. can insured_items contain a policy_id not in policies?)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT policies.policy_id, 
                insured_items.postcode, 
                insured_items.item_type  
FROM policies INNER JOIN insured_items 
WHERE policies.policy_id = insured_items.policy_id;
```

Comment: The issue here is that the query would return information that can be acquired by just doing a simple SELECT * FROM insured_items.
Like Gordon, I believe the question is a bit incomplete.